# Vuex - state's child property is read only, how to workaround?

Tags: vue.js

I have a vuex action that commits to a mutation:

```
updateStateProperty: (state, payload) => {
  state.parent.child = payload.changer // trying to modify child property - fail
}
```

This throws out a:

> ```
> TypeError: ""child" is read-only"
> ```

I've seen this example solution, but it's missing explanation for deepClone purpose:

```
   setSomething(state, payload) {
      let parent = deepClone(state.parent) // what is deepClone here?
      parent.child = payload.changer

      state.parent = parent
    }
```

Also seen other stuff but no clear code example. How should I go about changing this property?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Read-only I assume you're using Firefox as the error message would be different in other browsers. What are you doing to make it read-only in the first place? Perhaps creating it using `defineProperty` or freezing the object using `Object.freeze`?

Comment: Thanks for the input. As the first code suggests, I'm simply trying to modify a child property in a vuex store - that seems to be a vuex-specific error

Comment: Something is making that property non-writable and I don't believe it is Vuex. It is important to establish why that is happening before attempting a solution.

Comment: please refer: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/cannot-assign-to-read-only-property-of-object-object/9202

Comment: maybe it will clear something

Comment: Without a complete, minimal test case it is almost impossible to debug this for you. Something is making that property non-writable and you need to establish what that is. I would start by logging out the object and checking the getter/setter for that property to see whether they exist and where they are defined.